# XNA animation. Sprite does not draw on screen

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I followed a fairly simple video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNdDRfxW87k), in order to create an animation for my game. However, the player sprite does not draw on screen. I have put the animation code in my Player.cs and call the draw in Game1.cs. The problem is not in the order of the sprites being drawn, because it displays normally, without the animation code. It may be something very simple that I am over looking. Thank you, in advance. This is the relevant segments of code from the player class:

```
//Animation
float delay = 200f;
float elapsed ;
int frames = 0;
Rectangle destRect, sourceRect;
```

Initialize method:

`destRect = new Rectangle((int)playerLocation.X,(int)playerLocation.Y, 792, 87);`

Update method:

```
elapsed += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
if (elapsed >= delay)
{
    if (frames >= 3)
    {
        frames = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        frames++;
    }
    elapsed = 0;
}
sourceRect = new Rectangle(198*frames, 0 , 198, 87)
```

Draw method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(player, destRect,sourceRect, Color.White);
```

And I draw it in the Game1.cs `car.Draw(this.spriteBatch);`

Comment: So your animated sprite is all in one texture arranged horizontally?  I'm just trying to get an idea for your setup.

Comment: I assume `player` is a 594x87px `Texture2D` initialized somewhere else? And that you try to debug it and the `playerLocation` in `destRect` are valid coordinates?

Comment: `destRect = new Rectangle((int)playerLocation.X,(int)playerLocation.Y, 792, 87);` implies that a single frame of your player is 792 x 87, but your math for sourcerect is slicing only 198 x 87.  did you mean 197 in your destination?

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? Is the player not animating, not drawing in the proper location, or not drawing at all?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the draw call to make sure it is being called?

Comment: 1. There are 4 frames arranged horizontally.
2. The size of a single image is 198x87
3. I have tried putting 198 in the destination, but it still does not draw.
4. The image does not draw at all

Comment: Debug your code add breakpoints and watch them more than likely somethings is returning null or not the value expected.  Heres a link on how to debug http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn